# Confusion- Should I use CodeIgniter or something else for below case

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

As I have never develop any web-app from scrach. I want to know that:

**Background:**

I have to develop web-app whose **database will be on some other machine**[say server], and every **communication** with database has to be done **using SOAP web service**[database is on server]. I'm looking forward to use CodeIgniter framework to achieve this.

As CodeIgniter is MVC based, it has divided into

Module - can say storage

View - can say output

Controller - can say communicator between view and module

**Confusion:** Can I use Condigniter for app whose database is remote.

As I have seen tutorials and examples, all are of based on local database.

So can someone guide me, Is it possible to have all communication with database in same framework.

As much I have followed tutorials, flow is like(for local database)

Request: view -> controller -> module

Response: module -> controller -> view

so please tell me,how this will be in the CodeIgniter framework? Is it possible? What can be done? I'm confused,how to run app without the local database/how can I communicate with SOAP services using model class. or what to do? Or should I move to core php,if its not possible in CodeIgniter framework?? Please help me out. Thanks a lot!

IMP Update:**

Communication with database has to be done by only web service(SOAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, a CodeIgniter app has the following setting in your database configuration file:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
```

Instead of localhost, you should use whatever you have set up to connect to your external database.

Have a look at:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Note: You should not be asking if this is possible or not with CI. CI is a framework for building applications and it should be able to do what you want, don't think about what it can or can't do, think if it's the right tool for the job from an architectural standpoint.

Comment: So after this I can use SOAP client to request and response? What about webservice communication? not needed?

Comment: If you can connect to your external database, you can do whatever you do normally on localhost.